# Empty _FILES variable

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, html

I am trying to get full Adress of where my image is saved and then I want insert it into mysql database but I have a problem: $file is always empty.

Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

If I use $`_POST` except $`_FILES` I can get image name but not adress of where it is saved.

I am using this block of code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" enctypte="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image">
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
        </form>
        <?php
        echo $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `move_uploaded_file` to move the file to your desired location.

Comment: You're spelt encrypte wrong. It should be enctype

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` not `encrypte="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: i changed encrypte to enctype but still same problem

Comment: See Marc's answer and read the manual also http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: This `echo $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];` is also wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_FILES won't be populated until AFTER you've done an upload. when you first hit the form, you'll be dumping out an undefined array.

Basically, you need to check if an upload was performed AT ALL:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
       if ($_FILES['image']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
           die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['image']['error']);
       }
       echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   }
}
```

Comment: OP's code is wrong `encrypte="multipart/form-data"` which is the start of the big fail.

Comment: Looks like this one's dead in the water. Oh well, what can you do.